# How to create equivalent of IN clause but allowing AND of listed values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains ID and Keywords  I need to create that allow to select where 2 or more keyword are present
Example: Where keyword = 779 AND keyword = 782 should result in 4347

```
ID      Keyword
------------------
4347    779
4347    782
8853    779
8853    780
8853    787
```

I am using IN clause for letting user choose OR case Where Keyword IN (X,y,Z) is there something simlar Keyword IN (X AND Y AND Z) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming if ID 8975 had 7 key words 2 of which were 779 and 782 and you'd want that one as well...

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table
WHERE Keyword in (779,782)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(distinct keyword) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks! works great!

Comment: I believe that's the best solution - just need '>=2' as he said there could be more